# Is '0000-00-00' null in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, null, datefield

I'm cleaning up the warnings with my queries, and I have ran into the following error: `Code 1048: Column 'last_receipt' cannot be null`.

The query associated with the error takes all of the values from `table_B`.`on_dock` and puts them into `table_A`.`last_receipt` with a simple Update/Join statement.

However, there isn't a single value labeled as `null` in that column. There are, however, values labeled as `'0000-00-00'`. I've looked through the documentation and nothing says that `0000-00-00` is null but it seems as though MySQL definitely recognizes it as so. Is `0000-00-00` recognized as `null`, or am I just losing it today?

---------------------------------------- UPDATE --------------------------------

In my join query I connect `table_B` to `table_A` based on `order_id` with a subquery :

```
SELECT MAX(on_dock) AS max_on_dock FROM table_B GROUP BY order_id
```

Is the reasoning that these values come back as null possibly because of the MAX function?

---------------------------------------- UPDATE 2-------------------------------

When executing :

```
UPDATE table_B SET on_dock = '0000-00-00' WHERE on_dock IS NULL
```

It returns `0 rows affected`

When executing :

```
SELECT * FROM `table_B WHERE on_dock IS NULL
```

It returns 30,000 rows but all of the dates appear to be '0000-00-00'

When executing :

```
SELECT * FROM `table_B WHERE on_dock IS '0000-00-00'
```

It returns the same 30,000 rows

Comment: Only null is null. Everything else is not.

Comment: What rows are returned by `SELECT Table_B.on_dock from Table_B WHERE Table_B.on_dock IS NULL`?

Comment: _Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00')._ from [mysqldocs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

Comment: If you are using a recent release of MYSQL they have changed the rules on empty/invalid date/datetime columns

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8a07/2/0  returns no records, when searching for null but can't display 0000-00-00 as a date.

Comment: @RossPresser It brings up all of the rows where the date is '0000-00-00'

Comment: Are you by any chance using Connector/ODBC? The docs mention that it converts zero dates to **`null`**.

Comment: '0000-00-00' is when brain-eating zombies come out. Seems they found their first victim.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Nope :\

Comment: The only thing that;s really important here is your INSERT query. Please post that

Comment: @e4c5 As stated above, it is an UPDATE query, but the query is fine. The thing that is really important here is why mysql returns `'0000-00-00'` results when I ask for NULL values.